# Any Idea for Android app development

Tags: java, php, android, c++

Just wondering if anyone can help me in andriod app development. I'm new to this one and I dont know where to start.

Andriod app has extension name .apk and im thinking if it uses different language to develop or I can use PHP, JAVA or c++ to create an app then save the app as `.apk`.

Comment: Android applications are programmed in Java. Here's what a quick Google search gives me: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: People are -1'ing the new guy >.> If you're going to -1, at least explain why! +1 to offset -1

Comment: @ryan thanks for that. Well they think the are the best in this field trying to bully new forum-er i think. Im just asking for idea coz i know many people here have experience on this field

Comment: I gave +1. Yes. It's better to say why -1. And people should think about "New Guy" word too. So basically he asks "can I use PHP, JAVA or c++ to create an app then save the app as .apk?"

Comment: I gave you a -1 and a vote to close because you clearly spent exactly *zero* effort before posting this non-question.

Comment: @andrew so you are mr.knowitall?? im just asking for ideas and question if it is possible to use other language. is it a nonsense to you?? this forum is created to learn not to comment as if your the boss around here.

Comment: @Bert Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions), and lose the attitude. Just my recommendation. And by the way: Stack Overflow is *not* a "forum". Perhaps the fact that you think so is your problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Im new to this one and i dont know where to start.

Start here: http://developer.android.com/index.html

> andriod app has extension name .apk and im thinking if it uses different language to develop or i can use PHP, JAVA or c++ to create an app then save the app as .apk.

You can use ANY language than can generate Java bytecode. The official SDK provides Java API however and the NDK provides C/C++ one. The SDK provides a tool to create basic project structure with build scripts ready to use. If you're planning on using another language, you'll need to tweak the scripts.

Comment: thanks for this one. ill start learning this

Comment: @LELEdumbo.. i saw one app that is created with HTML,jsp. well it means i can use any language that provide java API.

Answer (score 0):

android apps runs on dalvik runtime, most of the time you see java but you can sometimes use c++ codes that will execute on linux as android is built on linuk kernal.